# What is the chemistry behind black colour of platinum black?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, transition-metals, color, colloids

**Platinum** is a silvery white metal and is highly unreactive then why it's powdered form **"platinum black"** is platinum metal but is black in colour. why would a metal such as platinum become black as a powder?

Comment: Might be related to light scattering from small particles of platinum (platinum black is a fine powder) vs. bulk, but not sure. Good question!

Comment: @ToddMinehardt is right, it's not about the chemistry, it's about the physics of how light interacts with it.  As good as a question as it is, I'm flagging it as off-topic for Chem.SE, as it more properly belongs on Physics.SE.

Comment: @ToddMinehardt For reference, [this answer](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/585/69087) on Physics.SE has a short paragraph about a related modification of $\ce{Pt}$ that also leads to a black color.

Comment: I wrote [a relevant answer](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/34014/1499) in a past question.

Comment: While the answer might be that's it's a physical effect rather than a chemical one, the question is still about a particular compound and the user wouldn't have known that it was a physical effect or else they wouldn't have asked here, so I'm glad the hold was removed.